# What is the best way to draw mind map in an Android app?

Tags: android, android-layout, graphics

I am writing an app for doing mind mapping. I have tried drawing a simple mind map using simple horizontal/vertical LinearLayouts and it gives a result like this

[image]

It looks like mind map but isn't beautiful enough. What I actually want is something like this:

[image]

I don't know how to draw something like that without manually specify the position of each node and able to adjust nodes' positions automatically when doing some actions, such as upon placing a new node among other existing nodes (that is, without calculating appropriate positions by myself) too.

Are there any techniques or libraries to help me do that?

Answer (score -1):

You can use an android open source is called [Mindo](https://github.com/JagarYousef/Mindo) 
With this library you can easily add your view using xml then adding the root, connections and childs programmatically.